# Laravel 8 CAN DELETE FROM DATABASE : The DELETE method is not

Tags: laravel

I've got the error "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST." when I want to delete some item in my database base on their's Id. Here is my code :

**index.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ $note->id }}" method="post" class="d-inline">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit"
        class="bg-red-500 text-white font-bold px-4 py-2 text-sm uppercase rounded tracking-wider focus:outline-none hover:bg-pink-400">
        Delete</button>
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('notes', NoteController::class);
});
```

**NoteController.php**

```
public function destroy(Note $note_id)
{
    //
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    Note::where(['user_id' => $userId, 'note_id' => $note_id])->delete();
    return $note_id;
}
```

How can I fix this error so I can delete my item from my database? Thank You :)

Comment: `action="{{ $note->id }}"` should be `action="{{ route('notes.destroy', [ 'id' => $note->id ]) }}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change the action param to `action="/notes/{{$note->id}}"`

you are not hitting that route . you are hitting `/{id}`

or use named routes `action="{{ route('notes.destroy', $note->id ) }}`

since you are using resource will make named routes for *store* *show* *destroy* and *update* all prefixed with name *notes.*

so if you need the destroy route you have to access */notes/id* named *notes.destroy*

you can use `php artisan route:list` to see all of your registered routes with their names and uris

Comment: Thank you for answering. your advice was true :D . and, the destroy parameter also must to changed into `(note_id)` , not `(Note $note_id)`